# how flutter state restoration is different from shared preference?

Tags: flutter

recently flutter rolled out state restoration I  want to know how it is different from shared preference
and in  ecommerce app can I restore list of product selected by user in shopping cart
thank you :)

Comment: For data such as cart which is stored in a list sort of manner. It is better to use a database to store that. BTW this is quite brief of a question.